# How to use ICommand for executing multiple methods after Buttonclick

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, icommand

I have a lack of understanding how to use the ICommand inferface for executing multiple methods in a row. Ideally I would like to create a delegate that executes all of the following 4 methods by invoking it (but it doesn't have to be a delegate):

```
var mongo = DbConn(); //Connection to MongoDB
var artikel = GetArtikel(reorderView); //returns ObservableCollection<ArtikelModel>
var reorder = GetReorder(artikel, reorderView); //returns ReorderModel
Insert(mongo, artikel, reorder); //inserts new reorder into the MongoDB database (one reorder has multiple articles(artikel))
```

**The View (excerpt):**

```
<Button Name="btnSave" Margin="3,0,3,0" Content="Save Reorder" 
                    BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Green" 
                    Height="30" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" 
                    Background="Green" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Command="{Binding SaveNb}">
</Button>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public partial class addReorder : System.Windows.Window
    {
        ReorderViewModel nachbest;
        ArtikelViewModel artikel;            

        //IControllerNachbestellung controllerNachbestellung;
        //IModelNachbestellung modelNachbestellung;
        public ObservableCollection<string> AnfCollection { get; set; }

        public addReorder() 
        {
            this.DataContext = new addReorderViewModel();
        }
    public addReorder(string hv)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //HV, BV, Projektleiter und Bauleiter holen
            var dbOracle = new Datenbank();
            txtBv.Text = dbOracle.GetBauvorhaben(hv);
            txtbHv.Text = hv;
            txtBauleiter.Text = dbOracle.GetBauleiter(hv);
            string pl = dbOracle.GetProjektleiter(hv);
            txtProjektleiter.Text = dbOracle.GetProjektleiter(hv);

            nachbest = new ReorderViewModel();
            artikel = new ArtikelViewModel();
            leftStPnl.DataContext = nachbest;
            rightStPnl.DataContext = nachbest;
            dgArtikel.DataContext = artikel;

            //Die Anforderungscollection wird befüllt         
            IAnforderungsgrund anfgruende = new Anforderungsgrund();
            AnfCollection = anfgruende.ListeAnforderungen();
            dgcbAnf.ItemsSource = AnfCollection;
            dgcbAnf.TextBinding = new Binding(AnfCollection.ToString());
        }
}
```

**The ViewModel (need help here):**

```
public class addReorderViewModel
    {
        //Hook to class DelegateCommand
        private readonly DelegateCommand<Button> _clickCommand;
        private ICommand saveNb { get; set; }


        public addReorderViewModel(addReorderView reorderview)
        {

        }
    public ICommand SaveNb
            {
                get
                {
                    return saveNb;
                }
                set
                {
                    saveNb = value;
                }
            }
```

The ViewModel has a "hook" to the DelegateCommand.cs-Class:
**DelegateCommand.cs**

```
public class DelegateCommand<T> : System.Windows.Input.ICommand
    {
        private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<T> _execute;

        public DelegateCommand(Action<T> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_canExecute == null)
                return true;

            return _canExecute((parameter == null) ? default(T) : (T)Convert.ChangeType(parameter, typeof(T)));
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute((parameter == null) ? default(T) : (T)Convert.ChangeType(parameter, typeof(T)));
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

*Questions:*

1. What do I have to do to make the buttonclick execute the above
   mentioned 4 methods?
2. How do I add other buttonclick events (the view has about 5-10 buttons) into the ViewModel?
3. How does the ViewModel know about the current View that is open?

**The methods inside the ViewModel:**

```
public MongoCRUD DbConn()
        {
            //Connection to MongoDB database "avdb"
            var mongo = new MongoCRUD("avdb");
            return mongo; //return value needed for INSERT-METHOD!
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Artikel> GetArtikel()
        {
            //How many rows inside the datagrid dgArtikel?
            int countrows = view.dgArtikel.Items.Count;
            //How many Columns?
            int countcols = view.dgArtikel.Columns.Count;

            //Arrays
            DataGridRow[] row = new DataGridRow[countrows];
            DataGridCell[] RowColumn = new DataGridCell[countcols];
            string[] CellValue = new string[countcols];
            string[,] ds = new string[countrows, countcols];

            ObservableCollection<Artikel> artikel = new ObservableCollection<Artikel>() { };
            //Save all cell values inside multidimensional Array
            for (int i = 0; i < countrows; i++)
            {
                //Create object for each DataGridRow of dgArtikel
                row[i] = (DataGridRow)view.dgArtikel.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                //Alle Spalten in der jeweiligen Zeile iterieren
                for (int j = 0; j < view.dgArtikel.Columns.Count; j++)
                {

                    RowColumn[j] = view.dgArtikel.Columns[j].GetCellContent(row[i]).Parent as DataGridCell;
                    //ATTENTION HARDCODING --> j==INDEX COMBOBOXCOLUMN!!!
                    if (j == 7) //<---!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    {
                        CellValue[j] = ((ComboBox)RowColumn[j].Content).Text;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CellValue[j] = ((TextBlock)RowColumn[j].Content).Text;
                    }

                    ds[i, j] = CellValue[j];
                }
                //The sequence must be the same as inside class ARTIKEL!  ATTENTION HARDCODING!
                var art = new Artikel
                {
                    Pos = ds[i, 0],
                    Artikelbezeichnung = ds[i, 1],
                    Artikelnummer = ds[i, 2],
                    Einheit = ds[i, 3],
                    Menge = ds[i, 4],
                    Einzelpreis = ds[i, 5],
                    Gesamtpreis = ds[i, 6],
                    Anforderungsgrund = ds[i, 7], //<---!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    Anforderungsnr = ds[i, 8],
                    Anforderer = ds[i, 9],
                    Bemerkungen = ds[i, 10]
                };
                if (art != null)
                    artikel.Add(art);
            }
            return artikel;
        }


         public ReorderModel GetReorder(ObservableCollection<Artikel> artikel, addReorderView reorderview)
         {             
            ReorderModel rom = new ReorderModel
            {
                Hv = view.txtbHv.Text,
                Bv = view.txtBv.Text,
                Bauleiter = view.txtBauleiter.Text,
                Empfaenger = view.cboxEmpfaenger.Text,
                Empf_Ansprechpartner = view.txtEmpfAnsprechpartner.Text,
                Empfaenger_Mail = view.txtEmpfMail.Text,
                Anlieferungsort = view.cboxAnlieferung.Text,
                Adressat = view.cboxAdressat.Text,
                Anschrift = view.txtAdresse.Text,
                Plz_Ort = view.txtPlzOrt.Text,
                Kontaktperson_Kontaktnr = view.txtAnsprechpartnerOrt.Text,
                Liefertermin = view.calLiefertermin.Text,
                Bearbeiter = view.cboxBearbeiter.Text,
                Telefon_Bearbeiter = view.txtBearbeiterTel.Text,
                Mail_Bearbeiter = view.txtBearbeiterMail.Text,
                Bestelldatum = view.calBestelldatum.Text,
                Bemerkung_oben = view.txtBemerkung.Text,
                Projektleiter = view.txtProjektleiter.Text,
                Angelegt_am = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                artikelliste = artikel
            };
            return rom;
         }  

         public void Insert(MongoCRUD mongo, ObservableCollection<Artikel> artikel, ReorderModel rom)
         {
            foreach (var a in artikel)
            {
                mongo.InsertRecord<Artikel>("bestellteArtikel", a);
            }
            mongo.InsertRecord<Nachbestellung>("nachbestellungen", nb);
            MessageBox.Show("Nachbestellung in Datenbank gespeichert!", "Erfolgreich!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
         }
```

**This is the view design:**
[image]
**This is the datagrid inside the view design (dummy example)**
[image]

**The GREEN BUTTON is the INSERT part I want to execute with the help of the ICommand interface, i.e. do the following after clicking:**

1. Connect to MongoDB
2. Get me the observableCollection()
3. Get me the ReorderModel instance
4. Do the Insert into my database collection

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Nachbestellungen.neueNachbestellung"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Nachbestellungen"      
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    FontFamily="Arial Narrow"
    Title="Nachbestellungen" Height="900" Width="900" FontWeight="Bold">


<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Abstand zwischen Textblock und Textbox automatisch setzen -->
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="uInputGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- links -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="25,25,0,0" x:Name="leftStPnl">
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlHeader" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Name="tbNb" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="NACHBESTELLUNG" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlBv" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbBv" Text="Bauvorhaben" DockPanel.Dock="Left" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox Name="txtBv" FontSize="12" DockPanel.Dock="Right" IsEnabled="False" Width="150" Margin="68,0,0,0"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlHv" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbHv" Grid.Column="0" Text="HV-Nummer" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtbHv" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="60" Margin="72,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlBauleiter" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbBauleiter" Text="Bauleiter" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBauleiter" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="150" Margin="90,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlGap1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlEmpfaenger" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbEmpfaenger" Text="AN" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboxEmpfaenger" FontSize="12" Width="150" Margin="118,0,0,0" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Changed">

            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlEmpfAnsprechpartner" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbEmpfAnsprechpartner" Text="Ansprechpartner" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtEmpfAnsprechpartner" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="150" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlEmpfMail" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbEmpfMail" Text="Mailadresse" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtEmpfMail" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="150" Margin="73,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlGap2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlAnlieferung" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="9" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbAnlieferung" Text="Anlieferung" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboxAnlieferung" FontSize="12" Width="150" Margin="77,0,0,0" Loaded="ComboBoxAnlieferung_Loaded" SelectionChanged="ComboBoxAnlieferung_Changed"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlBauherr" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="10" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbBauherr" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboxAdressat" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="200" Margin="135,0,0,0" DropDownClosed="CboxAdressat_DropDownClosed"/>

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlAdresse" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="11" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbAdresse" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Adresse"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAdresse" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="150" Margin="93,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlPlzOrt" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="12" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbPlzOrt" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtPlzOrt" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="150" Margin="135,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlGap3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="13" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlAnsprechpartnerOrt" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="14" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbAnsprechpartnerOrt" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Ansprechpartner&#10;vor Ort/Telefon"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAnsprechpartnerOrt" FontSize="12" Width="190" Margin="50,0,0,0" AcceptsReturn="False"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnKontakt" Content="Kontakt auswählen" FontSize="12" Click="btnKontakt_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlBemerkung" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="14" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbBemerkung" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Bemerkung"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBemerkung" FontSize="12" Width="250" Height="40" Margin="76,0,0,0" AcceptsReturn="False"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlLiefertermin" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="15" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbLiefertermin" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Liefertermin"/>
            <DatePicker x:Name="calLiefertermin" FontSize="12" Width="160" Margin="75,0,0,0" IsTodayHighlighted="true"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>

    <!--rechts-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,25,25,0" x:Name="rightStPnl">
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlLuxLogo" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="Z:\SchaeferT\Projekte\Haustechnik\Nachbestellungen\Nachbestellungen\LuxLogo.png" Width="200" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlFirma" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,27,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbFirma" FontSize="12" Text="Lux Projektmanagement GmbH &amp; Co. KG"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlFirmaAnschrift" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbFirmaAnschrift" FontSize="12" Text="Pleinfelder Straße 64"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlFirmaPlzOrt" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbFirmaPlzOrt" FontSize="12" Text="91166 Georgensgmünd"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlRightGap1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlBearbeiter" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbBearbeiter" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Bearbeiter"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboxBearbeiter" FontSize="12" Width="150" Margin="30,0,0,0" Loaded="ComboBoxBearbeiter_Loaded" SelectionChanged="ComboBoxBearbeiter_Changed"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlBearbeiterTel" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbBearbeiterTel" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Telefon"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBearbeiterTel" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="150" Margin="45,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlBearbeiterMail" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbBearbeiterMail" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Mail"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBearbeiterMail" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="150" Margin="62,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlBestelldatum" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbBestelldatum" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Best.-Datum"/>
            <DatePicker x:Name="calBestelldatum" FontSize="12" Width="200" Margin="19,0,0,0" IsTodayHighlighted="true"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlRightGap2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlRightGap3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlHinweis" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="11" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbHinweis" FontSize="12">
                <Run Text=" Bitte geben sie auf ihren Dokumenten immer folgende Informationen an:&#10;&#10;
 • Name des Bauvorhabens&#10;
 • HV-Nummer und/oder Kostenstelle&#10;
 • Name des Bestellers&#10;
 • Abholer (nur bei Abholungen)&#10;&#10;
Entsprechende Angaben sind in dieser Bestellung fett/kursiv markiert.&#10;&#10;"/>
                <Run FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="11" Text="Rechnungen mit unvollständigen Angaben müssen wir&#10; ab dem 01.12.2013 ungebucht an sie zurücksenden.&#10;"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlProjektleiter" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="14" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="tbProjektleiter" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Projektleiter"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtProjektleiter" Text="{Binding Projektleiter, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12" IsEnabled="False" Width="225" Margin="50,0,0,0" AcceptsReturn="False"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <!-- unten -->

    <DataGrid x:Name="dgArtikel" ItemsSource="{Binding Artikel}" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
              SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" IsReadOnly="False" 
              CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" RowHeight="30" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" FontSize="18" 
              LostFocus="DgArtikel_LostFocus" GotFocus="DgArtikel_GotFocus">
        <!-- Style Column Headers -->
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#DD002C"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,2"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pos" Binding="{Binding Pos}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artikelbezeichnung" Binding="{Binding Artikelbezeichnung}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artikelnummer" Binding="{Binding Artikelnummer}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Einheit" Binding="{Binding Einheit}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Menge" Binding="{Binding Menge}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Einzelpreis" Binding="{Binding Einzelpreis}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gesamtpreis" Binding="{Binding Gesamtpreis}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Anforderungsgrund" x:Name="dgcbAnf" ItemsSource="{Binding Anforderungsgrund}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Anforderungsnr" Binding="{Binding Anforderungsnr}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Anforderer" Binding="{Binding Anforderer}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bemerkungen" Binding="{Binding Bemerkungen}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Border x:Name="borderBtnArtikel" Grid.Row="2"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="25,0,0,0" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Background="PaleVioletRed" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Name="btnArtikel" Margin="3,0,3,0" Content="Artikel suchen" Height="30" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Background="PaleVioletRed" Click="BtnArtikel_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="PaleVioletRed"></Button>
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="borderBtnVorhanden" Grid.Row="2"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,25,0" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Name="btnVorhanden" Margin="3,0,3,0" Content="Vorhandene Nb Aufrufen" Height="30" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Background="Yellow" Click="BtnVorhanden_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Yellow"></Button>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2"  Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Background="Green" Margin="25,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Name="btnSpeichern" Margin="3,0,3,0" Content="Neue Nb Speichern" 
                BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Green" 
                Height="30" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" 
                Background="Green" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Command="{Binding SaveNb}"
                >
        </Button>
        <!-- Click="BtnSpeichern_Click" -->
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Background="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,25,0">
        <Button Name="btnOutlook" Margin="3,0,3,0" Content="Nb per Outlook versenden" Height="30" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Orange" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Background="Orange" Click="BtnOutlook_Click"></Button>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

As you can see, the Outlook operation (orange button) is still tightly coupled in a very bad design with the BtnOutlook_Click event handler inside the CodeBehind. So after binding the Green SaveNb Button properly to those 4 methods mentioned I would go on with this button and other buttons, decoupling them one by one from the CodeBehind for better reusable and flexible code according to standard conventions.

Comment: I noticed your ViewModel does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` - is this intentional? Are you using an MVVM framework? If you don't then you'll have to do a LOT of legwork and repetitive coding.

Comment: Also, your views should not be responsible for creating their ViewModels. You should be using constructor dependency injection. And your ViewModel **must not** have a dependency on your view.

Comment: Yes, I am using MVVM. In this ViewModel I just make an Insert. I am implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in another ViewModel which is responsible for updating and querying. Here I don't see any reason to implement it as it is just an insert (single direction, I save a new reorder to the database, that's it).

Comment: That's not how MVVM is meant to be implemented. I think you misunderstand how MVVM works.

Comment: @timunix You are right, you don't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you don't want the view to notify about changes e.g., in binding scenarios, where the data source changes. But you should consider to implement the interface in a base view model that all view models can inherit from. This way you don't need to re-implement it over and over again.

Comment: @Dai MVVM is not about Dependency Injection. It's about decoupling the business logic (model) from the view and to allow business code (the model) to be testable without depending on the view. This is achieved by introducing the binding technology, a view model as binding source and an unidirectional dependency graph which points from view to model. This means Dependency Injection is not a requirement by definition. Dependency Injection is an implementation of the IoC, a design pattern of its own, which aims to increase extensibility and testability.

Comment: @BionicCode I never said MVVM was about DI. I was making a reference to the OP's View creating an instance of the VM inside their View's constructor, which is bad design.

Comment: I will add the method definitions to make you understand what my way of thinking was. In 2 of my methods I am dependant on the view because I want to tell the ViewModel about the view's control contents (txtbHv.Text, txtBv.Text, etc.). I understand that I must not create an instance of the VM inside my view's constructor but how am I supposed to execute these methods if they don't know anything about the VIEW CURRENTLY OPEN (which is filled with textbox, combobox text input required for the database insert operation)?!

Comment: You have to make use of binding. Your views must bind to the view model. Then use `BindingMode.TwoWay` to propagate data from view back to the view model. What are your view dependencies? `reorderView`? Something else? Can you please post the complete view model that relates to the view and the view with the important or relevant controls that introduce the dependency? And the `addReorderView` too? What is it , a `DataGrid`? We can then fix your code together.

Comment: Yes, the only dependancy is the reorderView. I added the 4 ViewModel methods. I am aware that my code doesnt meet standard requirements but it is working. Nonetheless, I would love to know how to do the same operations without the view dependancy inside the ViewModel.

Comment: @BionicCode and Dai: Before I recently heard of the ICommand interface, I ran the above code inside the CodeBehind of the view inside the METHOD: btnClick_SaveReorder(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e). But then I realized that I need the observable collection artikel and reorder instance for another button (not just SaveReorder but also SendReorderWithOutlook(). And then I began to understand why tight coupling is bad design and landed here.

Comment: Is `reorderView` a `DataGrid` (`ItemsControl`)? Does it show instances of `Artikel`? What are your other mentioned controls showing (e.g. `txtbHv.Text`)? Also by the way you should adopt to the code convention of C# (or as used by Microsoft and the .NET library) and use Pascal Camel Case for public memebers and type names. And Camel Case for all other scenarios. It's not mandatory but it will look better. At least don't mix it. For most people the casing also carries information (e.g., public private or local). So this can be quite confusing.

Comment: reorderView is the View class, dgArtikel is the name of the datagrid inside this View class. txtbHv.Text is the Text inside one of multiple textboxes in the view. I show you the view for making this easier to understand. Note that if the View has loaded, all the standard data (above the datagrid) are already filled through a database query! Some fields can be selected with combobox selections. The datagrid itself only contains the Artikel data. One row is one Artikel instance. This is why I am using an observablecollection<Artikel>(). I will update my original post.

Comment: I didn't receive any notifications when the chat has activities. That's why I didn't respond. Do you got your problems solved?

Comment: @Bionic Code: Well yes, the problems have been solved so far. I moved all my code behind into the view model. Saving a reorder and sending it with outlook with a pdf attachment is just working fine. But now I need to update existing records. Maybe this issue should find another thread in this forum, though. Thanks for your help so far. I will notify you once I opened the new thread.

Comment: Good to hear from you and that you have fixed and cleaned up your code. Updating data records shouldn't be a big issue. Just let me know once you opened a new thread. By the way, I hope you didn't move view related code to the view model... See you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you are using `DelegateCommand` you just have to initialize it properly:

**AddReorderViewModel.cs**

```
public ICommand SaveNb => new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteMethods, CanExecuteMethods);

private void ExecuteMethods(object param)
{ 
  var mongo = DbConn(); //Connection to MongoDB
  var artikel = GetArtikel(reorderView); //returns ObservableCollection<ArtikelModel>
  var reorder = GetReorder(artikel, reorderView); //returns ReorderModel
  Insert(mongo, artikel, reorder); //inserts new reorder into the MongoDB database (one reorder has multiple articles(artikel))
}

private bool CanExecuteMethods(object param)
{ 
  // Check if command can execute 
  if (MongoDb connection exists)
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

2. For every other button that communicates with the view model use `ICommand` too. You just define new `ICommand` properties with new Execute and CanExecute delegates.
3. The view model should never know anything about the view. It should never operate on the view. The only way data is send to the view is to use `Binding` or events. The view itself knows when it's opened or visible and should then start to communicate with the view model.

Edit

View C# code:

```
public partial class addReorder : System.Windows.Window
{
    public addReorder(string hvId) 
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.DataContext = new addReorderViewModel(hvId);
    }
}
```

View model:

```
public class addReorderViewModel
{
  public addReorderViewModel(string hvId)
  {
    InitializeReorderModel(hvId);
    this.ArtikelList = new ObservableCollection<Artikel>();

    //Die Anforderungscollection wird befüllt         
    IAnforderungsgrund anfgruende = new Anforderungsgrund();
    this.AnfCollection = anfgruende.ListeAnforderungen();        
  }

  public InitializeReorderModel(string hvId)
  {
    this.Nachbest = new ReorderModel();

    //HV, BV, Projektleiter und Bauleiter holen
    var dbOracle = new Datenbank();
    this.Nachbest.BV = dbOracle.GetBauvorhaben(hv);
    this.Nachbest.Hv = hv;
    this.Nachbest.Bauleiter = dbOracle.GetBauleiter(hv);
    this.Nachbest.Projektleiter = dbOracle.GetProjektleiter(hv);
  }

  private void ExecuteMethods(object param)
  { 
    var mongo = DbConn(); //Connection to MongoDB
    var artikel = this.ArtikelList; //returns ObservableCollection<ArtikelModel>
    var reorder = this.Nachbest; //returns ReorderModel
    Insert(mongo, artikel, reorder); //inserts new reorder into the MongoDB database (one reorder has multiple articles(artikel))
  }

  public ICommand SaveNb => new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteMethods, CanExecuteMethods);

  public ReorderViewModel Nachbest {get; set;}
  public ObservableCollection<string> AnfCollection {get; set;}      
  public ObservableCollection<Artikel> ArtikelList {get; set;}      
}
```

XAML snippet:

```
<!-- links -->
<StackPanel x:Name="leftStPnl" DataContext="{Binding Nachbest}" ... >
    <StackPanel x:Name="pnlBv" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Name="tbBv" Text="Bauvorhaben" DockPanel.Dock="Left" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtBv" Text="{Binding Bv }" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="pnlHv" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Name="tbHv" Grid.Column="0" Text="HV-Nummer" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbHv"  Text="{Binding Hv}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    ...

</StackPanel>


<!-- rechts -->
<StackPanel x:Name="rightStPnl" DataContext="{Binding Nachbest}" ... >

    ...

</StackPanel>

<DataGrid x:Name="dgArtikel" ItemsSource="{Binding ArtikelList}" ... >
   ...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201910/discussion-on-answer-by-bioniccode-how-to-use-icommand-for-executing-multiple-me).

Answer (score 0):

Command in WPF is to execute one method when a command is generated from UI (button click). Now you have 4 methods to be executed on a command. So create one method (or Action) that contains the four method calls and bind that method to the command.

In the constructor of the view model add some thing like below

```
public addReorderViewModel()
{
    saveNb  = new DelegateCommand<Button>(() =>{
       var mongo = DbConn(); //Connection to MongoDB
       var artikel = GetArtikel(reorderView); //returns ObservableCollection<ArtikelModel>
       var reorder = GetReorder(artikel, reorderView); //returns ReorderModel
       Insert(mongo, artikel, reorder); //inserts new reorder into the MongoDB database (one reorder has multiple articles(artikel))
    });
}
```